# Differentiate between two shades of same colour

Tags: python, image, image-processing, histogram

I'm plotting histogram of banana images . I want to get the difference in shades of yellow between two pictures through histogram 
I have tried plotting the histogram and obtaining the peak value.
But the values obtained are similar and hence I'm not able to differentiate between the color shades.

I expect the peak value or y.max() to be in a different range for two different shades of yellow . But it lies in the same range

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('bansamnat10.jpg')

color = ('b' ,'g', 'r')
for i,col in enumerate(color):
    histr = cv2.calcHist([img],[i],None,[256],[0,256])
    plt.plot(histr,color = col)
    plt.xlim([0,256])
    x, y, _ = plt.hist(histr)
print (y.max())
plt.show()
```

Any help or suggestions or modifications are appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Matplotlib has a [`hist` method](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html). If you want to use it you can specify bin edges, suited to your data, with its `bin` parameter.

Comment: Maybe convert to a different [color space/model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_model#CIE_XYZ_color_space) and see if one produces better differentiation.